# Using R through PHP

Tags: php, r, command-line

I'm relatively new to R and very new to the Linux (Ubuntu) command line. I'm trying to write a page in PHP that contains a command I would like to execute in R and then pass the results back to be able to work with them. I've tried variations of the code below, but I only get the R welcome message as my output:

```
<?php

$rQuery = "\"echo 3 + 1;\" | /usr/bin/R --no-save";
exec($rQuery, $output);
print_r($output);

?>
```

When I manually type $rQuery in the command line the result is what I would expect: [1] 4.
I know I must be missing something towards the end there, but I haven't been able to figure it out through my own searching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. You want `--slave` as the option, it implies `--no-save` and turns the greeting off; see the manual for more.
2. What you *really* want is Jeff Horner's excellent *R-inside-Apache*, see [here for more](http://www.rapache.net).  It can use templating frameworks like [brew](http://cran.r-project.org/package=brew) as well.  Best of all, Jeff now provides a .deb package for you: use `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeffreyhorner/rapache/ubuntu lucid main` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
3. If you insist on piping from php, consider the [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) scripting frontend Jeff and I wrote. It will start faster than R.

Comment: 1. Thank you! You have no idea how much that was annoying me.  2. This looks very useful, I'll look into it once I get better at all this stuff.  3. This is exactly what I was look for. Thanks for writing it! In case anyone else is curious, I was able to get the exact result I was looking for by using:  "<?php $rQuery = "r -e 'cat(3+1)'"; system($rQuery); ?>"

Comment: Pleasure. Littler (eg `/usr/bin/r`) starts its embedded R instance with that option for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

For something this simple, you shouldn't even use PHP, 'cause you can do it solely with RApache, `brew` package and plain HTML (CSS/JS are optional). Just read [the RApache manual](http://rapache.net/manual.html) and see Jeroen Ooms' [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DfB_7_RZgasg). You should also read `brew` manual. Jeff really did a great job!

In a nutshell, you just need to setup **apache2.conf** or **.htaccess** file. Instead of using `<Directory>` or `<Location>` directives, you can use `<FilesMatch>` directive so you can match files with regexpr. Here's a sample **.htaccess**:

```
<FilesMatch "^.+\.rhtml$">
    SetHandler r-script
    RHandler brew::brew
</FilesMatch>
```

I use special file extension `.rhtml` where I mix HTML with R syntax within `<%` and `%>` tags (see `brew` documentation). I didn't use `brew` with PHP, 'cause `brew` with HTML did the trick.

Anyway, you said that you want to:

> write a page in PHP that contains a
>   command I would like to execute in R
>   and then pass the results back to be
>   able to work with them

- about executing commands from user input... well... don't do it! Especially don't allow users to execute custom commands 'cause they can easily pass `system` or `file.*` commands and mess your system up! You can use AppArmor, but it's still a long way down...
- focus on simple HTML forms and use **POST**, **GET**, **COOKIES**, **FILES** and **SERVER** variables that RApache provides, and then manipulate inputs within R script
- about "passing the results back", you can use either `XML` R package, or `rjson` (my favourite, and I recommend it). Then you can pass R object to `toJSON` function and unserialize it with JavaScript. Of course, that's true only if your clients are web-browsers, otherwise, if you, say, want to pass some info to embedded system, you should use the standard `XML`-way
- for something this simple, you don't need PHP. Anyway, you should contact Jeroen, I know he used some PHP in his [Stockplot](http://groups.google.com/group/rapache/) application

For any further questions, use [RApache mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rapache/).

...and hello R-webdev world! =)

Comment: Thanks. I agree with what you've said. For what it's worth I'm not planning on building a public web app with this- the server is running on a vm on my desktop and not connected to the internet. It's meant to be used within our department to automate some repetitive tasks. I just used PHP since I know it already and wanted to provide a simple browser interface for others to use. RApache looks great and I plan to use it once I get passed the basics.

Comment: That's OK. RApache should suffice. If you want to interact with R session in an open-ended way, try Rserve instead. RApache executes fresh R session on each HTTP request, so have that in mind. Just don't hardcode HTML within R script (with `cat` or `print`), and try to serialize/parse your data to JSON/XML and unserialize/deparse with JS or whatever. That's pretty much it... good luck! =)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever user apache is running as may not have the same environment variables, or permissions as when you ran it from the shell by hand.  Find out what user apache runs as, and make sure it has the right permissions and environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, I started running into this problem when trying more complex commands in R.